# How can I programmatically drop a Windows Mobile GPRS Connection?

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6, gprs

Is there a way to explicitly close a GPRS connection?
I'm setting up a connection with `ConnectionManager` and I've set the cache time to 10 seconds. Anyway after releasing it, the connection is still on, forever, alas I cannot use the registry key `gprs_by_if_device_off`. I'm using plain C++.

My idea is to simulate the activity of the windows button "disconnect data connection", but I really cannot understand what it does under the curtain.

Comment: Do you know of any exported RIL api that could help me? Thanx

Answer (score 2):

You need to terminate the remote access connection using RasHangUp with the handle you got from RasEnumConnections.

PS know that this answer is a bit late, but hope it helps someone! ;)

RasHangUp http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms897108.aspx , RasEnumConnections http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms897095.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look @ ConnMgrReleaseConnection ?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb416503.aspx

Comment: Hi Ranhiru,
of course I'm using it but it's a known "issue" that this API doesn't disconnect the GPRS connection :(.

Answer (score 0):

I believe so, but not in the way you'd probably hope.  Take a look at the SetDevicePower, PowerPolicyNotify, and SetPowerRequirement functions from CoreDLL.

By changing the power value for the RIL (Radio Interface Layer) you can "power down" the Radio, but still keep other parts of the system at partial levels or full power.

I actually do the opposite in several of my programs ... I need for the RIL to stay powered up (so I can manage backend communications with a Server) even though the handset wants to enter sleep mode (you also have to use the PowerPolicyNotify function on this to enable this behavior.  It's actually what Microsoft does that allows your handset to receive e-mails even though the device is in sleep mode - same thing.  You're simply going the other direction - powering it down instead.